# How to use EndPoints to generate API library in Objective-C in Google App Engine

Tags: ios, api, google-app-engine, endpoints

I used google app engine as my backend server. I watched the google I/O video, and it said it can generate the IOS api library in EndPoints by command line. But I couldn't find the way to do that, and there is no information about it on the Internet. Is there anyone who uses google app engine as their IOS app backend and could answer my question?

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Endpoints is still under Trusted Tester program.
You can sign up here:

http://endpoints-trusted-tester.appspot.com/

**UPDATE** Official docs on generating iOS client libs can be found here:

- [Python](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/gen_clients#generating_a_discovery_doc_for_ios_using_maven)
- [Java](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/gen_clients#generating_a_discovery_doc_for_ios)

Answer (score 0):

Working with GAE, there is no way to generate an API **"in objective-c"**. Google app engine infrastructure supports Java and python, so you need to write your API in one of these languages to deploy it in GAE cloud.

Then, in your iOS application, you will need to communicate with the APIs you just deployed in GAE, this can be done with a so called `client library`. Here is an example of a [client library for Objective-C](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/).